# Why do I get this json syntax error when trying to program homebridge?

Tags: json

noob here.  I am trying to program my homebridge to accept a new dyson fan. Thanks to joe-ng who wrote it. https://github.com/joe-ng/homebridge-dyson-link

This is what I'm inputting and keep getting a syntax error warning:

```
{
"bridge": {
    "name": "Homebridge C81F",
    "username": "mac:address:of:rasberrypi",
    "port": 88888,
    "pin": "031-45-154"
},
"accessories": [],
"platforms": [
    {
        "platform": "DysonPlatform",
        "name": "DysonPlatform",
        "email": "my-email",
        "password": "my-password",
        "country": "UK",
        "accessories": [
            {
                "ip": "192.168.0.88",
                "displayName": "Bedroom Fan",
                "serialNumber": "VS7-UK-SERIALNO",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried using JSONLint and it is telling me expecting string, so I thought it was commas but I'm not very experienced so would appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have it in a `file.json`, then you can display the file with the jq program.
For your json, the `jq` program returns an error:

```
> jq '.' file.json
parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 21, column 13
```

After you remove comma (`,`), you have next error:

```
➜  ~ jq '.' file.json
parse error: Unfinished JSON term at EOF at line 25, column 0
```

After you add missing bracket (`}`), you get:

```
{
    "bridge": {
        "name": "Homebridge C81F",
        "username": "mac:address:of:rasberrypi",
        "port": 88888,
        "pin": "031-45-154"
    },
    "accessories": [],
    "platforms": [
        {
            "platform": "DysonPlatform",
            "name": "DysonPlatform",
            "email": "my-email",
            "password": "my-password",
            "country": "UK",
            "accessories": [
                {
                    "ip": "192.168.0.88",
                    "displayName": "Bedroom Fan",
                    "serialNumber": "VS7-UK-SERIALNO"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```